# Flow control after breaking out of while loop in Python

Tags: python, while-loop, control-flow

I am pretty new to both programming and Python. A few times now, I have created what feels like an awkward program flow,  and I am wondering if I am following best practices. This is conceptually what I have wanted to do:

```
def pseudocode():
    while some condition is true:
        do some stuff
        if a condition is met:
            break out of the while loop
    now do a thing once, but only if you never broke out of the loop above
```

What I've ended up doing works, but feels off somehow:

```
def pseudocode():
    while some condition is true:
        do some stuff
        if some condition is met:
            some_condition_met = True
            break out of the while loop

    if some_condition_met is False:
        do a thing
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're looking for [`while-else`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#while) loop:

```
def pseudocode():
    while some condition is true:
        do some stuff
        if a condition is met:
            break out of the while loop
    else:
        now do a thing once, but only if you never broke out of the loop above
```

From docs:

```
while_stmt ::=  "while" expression ":" suite
                ["else" ":" suite]
```

> A `break` statement executed in the first suite terminates the loop
>   without executing the `else` clause’s suite.

Comment: Whoa, did not now that existed (obviously!). Thx.

Answer (score 3):

Use an `else` clause to the `while` loop:

```
while some_condition:
    do_stuff()
    if a_condition_is_met:
        break
else:
    executed_when_never_broken
```

See the [`while` statement documentation](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-while-statement):

> A `break` statement executed in the first suite terminates the loop without executing the `else` clause’s suite.

Answer (score 0):

If you think about it, you might already have a perfectly good condition to use without setting a flag: the condition at the top of the while loop (or, rather, the `not` of it). Assuming you don't change the truthiness of your condition during the same iteration as a `break`, this gives you:

```
while something:
    do_stuff()
    if something_else:
        break
if not something:
   more_stuff()
```

This makes sense if you think of `while` as a repeated `if`: instead of happening once, a while *keeps going* until the condition becomes falsey.

But, like the other answers have mentioned, the analogy goes further: just like you don't have to spell all your `if`s as

```
if a:
    a_stuff()
if not a:
    b_stuff()
```

`while` accepts an `else` that is executed if the condition at the top is tested and found to be falsey. So,

```
while something:
    do_stuff()
    if something_else:
       break
else:
    more_stuff()
```

And, same as the `if`/`else` case, this doesn't imply any further tests of the condition than what would happen anyway. In the same way that an `else` attached to `if a` won't run if the true-branch makes `a` falsey, an `else` attached to a `while` will never run after a `break` since that explicitly skips ever checking the condition again. This makes the `else:` equivalent to a decicated flag in every case.

This also extends to `for` loops, even though the analogy breaks - but it executes under similar enough rules: the `else` is run if the loop ends by having run its course rather than hitting a `break`.

Comment: Note that the `else:` clause and the `if not something` test can subtly differ. If the `while` loop condition becomes `False` during the loop **and** you use `break` during that same iteration, then the `else:` suite will not execute, but your `if` suite will.

Comment: @MartijnPieters very true. I've edited the answer to account for that.